# Repeated possessive (ex. 'of mine,' or 'of Trump's')

Tags: phrase-usage, possessives, double-possessives

> Mr. Brooks, a hard-right Republican and **a once-fierce ally of Mr. Trump’s whom the former president has accused of becoming “woke,”** has drawn intense scrutiny for his actions preceding the violence on Jan. 6.
> [NYT, Abandoned by Trump, Mo Brooks Is Now Open to Testifying About Jan. 6, Jun. 23, 2022](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/06/23/us/politics/mo-brooks-jan-6-testify.html?searchResultPosition=2)

This is an excerpt from an NYT article. I don't figure out the exact meaning of the bolded part. I think it could be simply put as "a once-fierce ally of Mr. Trump, who has accused him of becoming woke." Is there any specific reason to write like this?

Comment: Where is the term "one's whom"?? The NYT's sentence is fine. Yours is not grammatical.

Comment: What does "ex. 'of mine'"mean?  Do you mean **e.g.**, which is the abbreviation for "for example"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[...]  a once-fierce ally of Mr. Trump’s whom the former president has accused of becoming “woke,

"who has accused him of becoming woke" would be confusing.

When you use **who** to introduce a dependent clause, it refers to an antecedent, which here is Mr. Trump. So that would not work.

Sometimes people use the former and the latter: The latter has accused the former of becoming woke. But that would require completely changing everything.

[...] a good friend of my brother's **whom I saw** in the street.

the whom is formal, as a direct object of accused.

Comment: Thanks first. but still confused a bit. To me, "of Mr. Trump's" seemed a repeated possessive form. So I was curious if there is any usage of the form 'one's whom' that I am not aware of.

Comment: No, we say a friend of mine. A friend of his. But with a name we say: A friend of John's or A friend of Betty's. It's just idiomatic. I still do not understand why you are using "one's whom".

Comment: Oh, a friend of mine. that makes sense. It was not a that complicated problem lol. thank you.

Comment: @MesutOezil Consider the difference between *a picture/portrait/image/sculpture of Leonardo* and *a picture/portrait/image/sculpture of **Leonardo’s***. The version **without** the possessive says nothing about the ownership or authorship of the thing, while the one that has a real possessive very much **does** do so. Same with *a record of your mother* versus *a record of your **mother’s***, and with *a picture of you* versus *a picture of **yours***.

Comment: @tchrist This helps a lot. I haven't thought about this difference. Many thanks!